# Is there a Heroku for Django?

Tags: django, heroku

I've been looking into Heroku as a hosting provider.  I'm specifically interested in its ease of deployment and ability to scale up and scale down resources as needed.

Is there a hosting solution with this type of ease and power that works with Django?

Comment: Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/259981/python-equivalent-to-heroku

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Djangy.com have shut down, but they have recommendations for python/django hosting services:

- [gondor.io](https://gondor.io/)
- [djangozoom.com](http://djangozoom.com/)
- [dotcloud.com](https://www.dotcloud.com/)

I haven't tried any of them, but they all seem pretty proactive!

[edit] I have to add the people who pay my salary too!

- [PythonAnywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com)

Super-awesome, obviously :-)

[edit]

And, since september '11, there's Heroku themselves!

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/9/28/python_and_django/

Comment: ep.io has shut down unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can find is [Djangy.com](http://djangy.com/), but it is currently in private beta.  It seems to be the equivalent of Heroku for Django.  As soon as it is out, I will be one of the first on it.

Comment: What are you using now for Django host?

Comment: Djangy.com has been shut down.

Answer (score 6):

Starting today, Heroku provides official support (public beta) for Python and Django!
Check out this blog post http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/9/28/python_and_django/ and this guide http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Answer (score 5):

You may also be interested in http://DjangoZoom.com. I'm a founder, and we'd love to have your feedback on our beta.

Answer (score 4):

You can run django on Heroku as well. There's a good writeup at http://blog.abhiomkar.in/2011/09/17/deploying-django-on-heroku-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 3):

Heroku recently announced that they are now supporting Django and Python.

So technically speaking - Yes