# Python equivalent to Heroku

Tags: python, cloud-hosting

Is there a Heroku or Engine Yard equivalent for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mnn, not quite. **As of early 2011 there are several promising projects in this space,** but nothing that has reached the level of maturity and size of Engine Yard.

From [this excellent list by Graham Dumpleton:](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2011/01/awesome-year-for-python-web-hosting.html)

- [AppHosted](https://apphosted.com/)
- [djangozoom](http://djangozoom.com/)
- [Djangy](https://www.djangy.com/)
- [ep.io](http://www.ep.io/)
- [Gondor.io](https://gondor.io/)
- [Pydra](http://www.pydra.com/)
- [stable.io](http://stable.io/)

Several of these are early stage / under development, so a comparison can't really be made yet.

In addition to the above startups, there is [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) with its special & limited Python runtime, and [maybe also Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/). Joyent used to be very Engine Yard alike, a value added & scalable web host, but now I really can't figure out their current marketing / market position. But you might want to give them a call.

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent to Heroku for Python is...  Heroku.  They recently added full Python support.

Answer (score 1):

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) comes to mind.
We're going to need more details about what features you are looking for in order to adequately answer your question.